# How can I associate zero-based values from two arrays when the first array is set to display a random value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output the values from 2 arrays, where the first array outputs a random value while the second array outputs the corresponding zero-based value.

e.g. if ".285" is the random value from the bAvg array, only "22" populates from the hrs array.

Right now I get two random outputs.  I am new to JS, so don't have a lot of comprehension at this point.

HTML:

```
<p id="avg"></p>
<p id="hr"></p>
```

JS:

```
var bAvg = [".349", ".285", ".202"];
var hrs = [22, 42, 6];

document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = bAvg[Math.floor(Math.random() * bAvg.length)];

for (var i = 0; i < bAvg.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("hr").innerHTML =(hrs[i]);
}
```

OUTPUT:

Currently: random values from each array

Comment: Can you explain how exactly the `bAvg` and `hrs` arrays are related? What does "the corresponding zero-based value" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to get the index of the randomly-selected value from the `bAvg` array to get the item at the same index of the `hrs` array

```js
const bAvg = [".349", ".285", ".202"];
const hrs = [22, 42, 6];

const randAvg = bAvg[Math.floor(Math.random() * bAvg.length)];
const hr = hrs[bAvg.indexOf(randAvg)];

document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = randAvg;
document.getElementById("hr").innerHTML = hr;
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="avg"></p>
  <p id="hr"></p>
</body>
```

Note: I would also recommend checking that the two arrays have the same length